# ADAM abstraction at LDAP call level

Tags: .net, ldap, adam

I have an ADAM directory that our application needs to interface with.
Currently we have an abstraction such that our repository uses Sql Server instead of making hte appropriate LDAP calls. We'd like to get closer to our integration point and utilise our actual LDAP repository instead.

The problem is that this slows down our dev scenario. We very much have an 'Get Latest -> F5' experience and the app 'just works'. Introducing this integration point in its entirety will kill that for us and we don't want to do it (completely).

Yes we could all run VMs with ADAM on it, but there's a lot of overhead in that. We also have a centralised server we could use but its slow to connect to (we work remotely over 3G connections and its a 5 second round trip for an LDAP lookup).

So what I am wondering if there is a way to hook into the LDAP protocol, intercept those calls and redirect them to XML or a database of somesort. I've heard of this kind of thing being available (heresay!) but could not find anything in the .Net world (I think this was Java).

So basically I am looking for anyone who has solved a similar problem, or knows of a way to hook into LDAP calls. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use #if DEBUG to go to your DB for debug builds, like you do now, and go to the LDAP  repository in release builds.